# Proof of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

(a) First, prove Bernoulli’s Inequality: if $1+ p > 0$, then for all $n ∈ ℤ^+$, $(1+p)^n \geq 1+np$.

(b) Since $0 < x < 1$, there exists $y > 0$ such that $x = \frac{1}{1+y}$. Show that $x^n < \frac{1}{ny}$.

(c) Finally, use part (b) (and the Squeeze Rule) to show that if $0< x < 1$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x^n = 0$.

Workings:

a.

Proof:

Base Case: $n = 1$

$(1+p)^1 = 1+p$

$1+(1)p = 1+p$

$1+p \geq 1+p$

Base case holds.

Induction Hypothesis:

Suppose this holds for $P(k)$ where $k \geq 0$

That is

$(1+p)^k \geq 1+kp$

Then for $k+1:$

$(1+p)^{k+1}$

$= (1+p)^k (1+p)$

$\geq (1+pk)(1+p)$

$= 1 + (k+1)p + kp^2$

$\geq 1+(k+1)p$

This holds by induction

b.

Proof:

$x^n = \left(\frac{1}{1+y}\right)^n$

$\leq \frac{1}{1+ny}$

$< \frac{1}{ny}$

Now I'm not sure if I did part b right and I'm not too sure about part c.

I know that the squeeze theorem states that:

Suppose that suppose $\left(a_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\left(c_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are sequences such that for all $n \in ℤ^+$, $a_n <= b_n < c_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}c_n = L$. Then \lim\limits_{n + to \infty} b_n = L$ also.

So I know that"

$0 < x^n < \frac{1}{ny}$ Should I apply squeeze theorem on that.

Comment: Why is $x\in (0,1)$? Is this an assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a good job in $a)$ and $b)$. As for $c)$, yes, that's what you should do.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just the definition of the limit? $x^n<\epsilon$ if $n>\ln\epsilon/\ln x$.